# How to create copitables dotted horizontal lines?

Tags: html, css, copy-paste, horizontal-line

One can use this code to create a dotted horizontal line:

```
<hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />
```

However, the line is uncopiable. If I want my users to be able to copy it like how regular text be copied and pasted, what should I do?

<sub>FYI: [How To Style the HR Element with CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_style_hr.asp)</sub>

Comment: What did you expect with the idea of copying a line?

Comment: It's a questionnaire that users can self-answer it. I do realize that I can attach a Word document so they can download it instead of copying the website, but then I have to update two files instead of one. Plus I want to learn more about CSS

Comment: It still doesn't make sense that you want to copy the border?!?!

Comment: @famoha which border? The one in my sample code? It's just a trick to create dotted horizontal line. But if I am to make a copitable line, I may not need to use that trick